# Find the Laurent series about $z_0=0$ for the following function, valid in the indicated regions.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

$$\frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{1}{z+1}, \qquad 2<|z|<\infty$$

I am not sure how to approach this question. Can anyone help me with this question?
Thank you.

Comment: what does in2 mean??

Comment: @Faraad: I presume it is meant to read  for $z \in \{ z | 2 < |z| \}$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant for $|z| > 2$ (and so $\frac{1}{|z|} < \frac{1}{2} < 1$):

$\frac{1}{z+1} = \frac{1}{z} \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{z}} = \frac{1}{z} (1-\frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{z} - \cdots)$.

Similarly for the other term.

Comment: In that case, I agree with this. :)

Comment: :-) ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering my question. Can you please give me a more detailed answer. Sorry, I am not good at mathematics. :)

Comment: I am happy to assist you. What part of the above you not understand? Can you see how you can use what I did to find the expansion of $\frac{1}{z-1} = -\frac{1}{1-z} = -\frac{1}{1+(-z)}$?

Comment: Hi, do you mean that I should write $\frac{1}{z-1}$ as $-\frac{1}{1+(-z)}$ and follow the steps of $\frac{1}{z+1}$, then I can get the answer of this question? Thanks.

Comment: And then subtract the two...

Comment: @copper.hat: thank you very much for helping me with this question.